# UITableviewcell is wrong data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've created a custom UITableViewCell, and the cell has two UITableViews.

And each of them has UITableViewCell. like this

- View

  - UITableView --(WrapTableView)

    - UITableViewCell

      - StackView

        - UITableView --(InformationTableView)

          - UITableViewCell
        - UITableView --(ItemTableView)

          - UITableViewCell

And My code is like this,

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var wrapTableView: UITableView!
  // ... //
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
                  as? WrapTableViewCell else {
              return UITableViewCell()
          }      
          cell.setup()
          return cell
      }
  }
}

class WrapTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var informationTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemTableView: UITableView!
    
    let informationTableViewDelegate = InformationTableViewDelegate()
    let itemTableViewDelegate = itemTableViewDelegate()
   
    func setup(){
      self.informationTableView = informationTableViewDelegate
      self.itemTableView = itemTableViewDelegate
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
      //...
      //What should I write?
      ...//
    }
}

class InformationTableViewDelegate: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
   guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: InformationTableViewDelegateCell.identifier) as? InformationTableViewDelegateCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }        
   cell.setup(text: text)
   return cell

}

class ItemTableViewDelegate: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
   guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ItemTableViewDelegateCell.identifier) as? ItemTableViewDelegateCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }        
   cell.setup(itemPrice: itemPrice)
   return cell
}


class InformationTableViewDelegateCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var itemNameLabel: UILabel!

    func setup(text:String){
       self.itemNameLabel.text = text
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
      //...
      //What should I write?
      ...//
    }
}

class ItemTableViewDelegateCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var itemPriceLabel: UILabel!

    func setup(itemPrice:String){
       self.itemPriceLabel.text = itemPrice
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
      //...
      //What should I write?
      ...//
    }
}
```

My problem is, during scrolling, old cell is still shown.

I understand that I have to reset old data using prepareForReuse method to reset all of dates.

But, in my case, I don't know what to write in each of prepareForReuse() method, because, for example, the WrapTableViewCell's property is not like image or Label, though in those cases, image.image = nil or label.text = "" is applied, but like tableviews which are attached by IBOutlet


Thanks

Comment: “I understand that I have to reset old data using prepareForReuse method to reset all of dates.” You might understand wrong. The methods of concern are the UITableViewDataSource methods, especially `cellForRow`.  Your cell setup needs to be, or be accompanied by, a configure method that configures _everything_ about the cell.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use prepareForReuse method. you need to reload data to pass to table view just